# Migrate cluster Aurora RDS postgres from 9.X to 10 without downtime

Tags: postgresql, aws, amazon-rds-aurora

Ok, this question is to find some strategy or tool that helps me to migrate from cluster Aurora RDS postgres from 9.6 to 10 without downtime.

What I find until now

- Aurora RDS is allowed to do major upgrades in-place (cluster aurora don't)
- DMS just can run full-load without keep sync from postgres 9.6 source :/ (sync just in the postgres 10)

kinesis and DMS depends in the logical replication slot whose cluster aurora release just in the postgres 10 :(

In my mind now I have 2 strategies

- Migrate database one by one with really small downtime. I will need to do backup/restore and redeploy the application because the route53 references there will be two during the migration
- Create a strategy/application to join DMS + trigger + aws lambdas
  DMS to full load, trigger to register updates and lambda to read the updates and do the data migration to keep data sync between the servers until the update in the endpoint below the route53 (it's a lot of responsibility to one single dba)

This is what I have know with you know some tool or more interesting strategy please send me :D

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html